# Valor de uma variavel se torna o valor da id

Tags: javascript, html

negocio é o seguinte: quero jogar um valor de uma variável js para se tornar o id de uma div no html.

```
<script>var x= 3;</script> 
<div id = "{x}"></div>
```

acima é um exemplo visual pq provavelmente não existe jeito de dar property binding com javascript puro.
me ajudem por favor!!

Comment: Jeito tem, se não tivesse o AngularJS (v1) não funcionaria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var x= 3;

//Loop em todos os elementos da página
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
    //Loop na lista de atributos do elemento
    for (const attribute of element.getAttributeNames()) {
        //Pega o atributo
        let attr = element.getAttribute(attribute);
        //Usa regex para pegar as variaveis
        const match = attr.match(/\{[^\{\}]+\}/g);
        //Se houver alguma
        if (match != null) {
            //Faz um loop, porque pode ser mais de uma
            for (let bindVariable of match) {
                //Retira o primeiro e último caracter, respectivamente, "{" e "}"
                bindVariable = bindVariable.substr(1, bindVariable.length-2);
                //Defini o novo atributo
                element.setAttribute(attribute, window[bindVariable]);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Mostra o elemento pelo novo id
console.log(document.getElementById(x));
```

```html
<div id="{x}"></div>
```

Esse código tem quatro problemas (ou mais):

1. Faz muitos loops, incluindo um deles é sobre **TODOS** elementos HTML na página, o que pode prejudicar consideravelmente a performance
2. As variáveis usadas para fazer o *binding* precisam ser declaradas antes do código ser executado, e os demais códigos que usam aquela propriedade com o novo valor precisam ser executados depois
3. Esse código supõe que todas as variáveis estejam no escopo do objeto `window`, o que pode não ser verdade
4. Isso é apenas uma versão simples, alterar o valor do X depois do loops não atualiza os valores nos elementos HTML

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer dessa forma, mas caso tenha mais `divs` na tela precisa identificar ela de alguma forma, pois só informando a `div` ele vai adicionar o `id` para todas as `divs` do documento.

```js
var x= 3;
$('div').prop('id', x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>teste</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Tente utilizar HTML DOM id Property

```
document.getElementById("myAnchor").id = "newid";
```